# Function returns None

Tags: python, python-2.7

After making an error then doing recursion i get None.

```
def getplayerinput():
    a = ["rock","paper","scissors"]
    plin = raw_input("Choose %s/%s/%s: " %(a[0], a[1], a[2]))
    print plin,'-first print'
    if plin not in a:
        print "Wrong input"
        getplayerinput()
    else:
        print plin,'-second print'
        return plin

for i in range(0,11):
    print getplayerinput()
```

If you input first 'rock' then 'cat' then 'paper' you will get a 'None'.

Comment: you must `return getplayerinput()` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not return anything once the input is not valid. Do this instead:

```
def getplayerinput():
    a = ["rock","paper","scissors"]
    plin = raw_input("Choose %s/%s/%s: " %(a[0], a[1], a[2]))
    print plin,'-first print'
    if plin not in a:
        print "Wrong input"
        return getplayerinput() # <- added return
    else:
        print plin,'-second print'
        return plin

for i in range(0,11):
    print getplayerinput()
```

Otherwise the recursion call will return something to a top level call, but that one just swallows the return value from the recursion call, since it doesn't pass it on via return.